# To prove ${2p - 1 \choose p } \equiv 1 \pmod{p^2}$ without using Wolstenholme's theorem

Tags: number-theory, binomial-coefficients, divisibility, congruences

How to prove  that ${2p - 1 \choose p} \equiv 1 \pmod{p^2}$ ? I don't want to use  Wolstenholme's theorem; but one might use $p|{p \choose k} , 1 \le k \le p - 1$ , and $(p - 1)! \sum_{k = 1}^{p - 1} \dfrac 1k \equiv 0 \pmod p$. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

We have:
$$(p-1)!\cdot\binom{2p-1}{p}=\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}(p+k)= (p-1)!\cdot(1+p H_{p-1})+Kp^2\tag{1}$$
for some $K\in\mathbb{N}$. Now it is well known that $H_{p-1}\equiv 0\pmod{p}$.

Since $(p-1)!\equiv -1\pmod{p}$, we have that $(p-1)!$ is invertible $\pmod{p^2}$,

hence the previous line easily gives:
$$\binom{2p-1}{p}\equiv 1\pmod{p^2}\tag{2}$$
as wanted.

Comment: Could you please explain how you wrote the product in the first line as $(p-1)!\cdot(1+p H_{p-1})+Kp^2$ ?

Comment: @user123733: Rewrite $\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}(p+k)$ as it was a polynomial in $p$. The value in zero is given by $(p-1)!$, the coefficient of $p$ is given by $H_{p-1}(p-1)!$ and all the other terms are integer multiples of $p^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$\binom{2p-1}{p-1} = \binom{2p-1}{p}$$ 
Using Pascal's Identity we have that
$$\binom{2p-1}{p-1} + \binom{2p-1}{p} = \binom{2p}{p}$$
Now applying [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) taking m = r = p we have the following:
$$2\binom{2p-1}{p} = \binom{2p}{p} = \sum_{k=0}^p \binom{p}{k}^2$$
Hence
$$ \frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \binom{p}{k}^2 \right) = \binom{2p-1}{p} -1 $$